# How can I start service from an adapter class in xmarine android c#?

Tags: c#, android, service, background-service

How can I start service from an adapter class in xmarine android c#? I am trying the below mentioned code from my adapter class, but it gives me error.

```
var intent = new Intent(action);
intent.SetPackage("App1Test.App1Test");
StartService(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Xamarin but the following can give you an Idea -

Either include a `Context` variable in Adapter & initialize it in Adapter's constructor by adding a Context parameter to Adapter's constructor or use the Context of your Inflated View in the Adapter (`view.getContext()`) & then that context can be used for starting the Service like:

```
Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(service);
```